# Why I got an attributeError after create database?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I create the database and try to connect the market page.
But I got this error here.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util_collections.py", line 1008, in **call**
return self.registry[key]
KeyError: <greenlet.greenlet object at 0x0000026A2C0F5300 (otid=0x0000026A2C10AE80) current active started main>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2088, in **call**
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy_*init*_.py", line 914, in apply_driver_hacks
sa_url.database = os.path.join(app.root_path, sa_url.database)

AttributeError: can't set attribute

My code is here.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///market.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False, unique=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    barcode = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=False, unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(1024), nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Item {self.name}'


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home_page():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/market')
def market_page():
    items = Item.query.all()
    return render_template('market.html', items=items)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My requirements.txt is here

```
click==8.0.2
colorama==0.4.4
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.0
greenlet==1.1.2
install==1.3.4
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.2
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
SQLAlchemy==1.3.23
Werkzeug==2.0.2
```

I really want to know what happend is going on.

Comment: I change the version of  Flask-SQLAlchemy  to  2.5.
I change the version of SQL Alchemy to 1.3.23.
But it still didn't work.

Comment: Yes, still the same attribute error!

Comment: I execute (pip freeze > requirements.txt)